# Can I grant append-only permission to a google drive file?

Tags: google-drive-api

I am developing an iOS app to manage data for a company.  I would like to maintain the data files in a single Google Drive and grant full access to a DBA, view access to all users, and append-only access to some.  The different access permissions could be granted based on different passwords used to log into the Google Drive, but that doesn't seem to be the way Google Drives are setup.  So I am creating one DBA-level Username-password Google Drive with "owner" access to all the files and one User-level Username-password to another Google Drive which shares "view-only" access to one folder in the DBA Google Drive and "edit" access to another folder in the DBA Google Drive.  However, I would like the "edit" access to be limited to "append" only, but I doubt that option is available (yet).  I want non-DBA users to be able to add data but not be able to delete data.  How can I make this work using only Chrome-Google-Drive and iOS app functionality.  I don't want to implement a server running MySql (e.g.) for each company that uses this app.  I just want to create one or two unique Google Drives for each company.  My app maintains a list of company employees with individual passwords that can be used to hold access permissions, but since the app uses the standard Google Drive Sign-In dialog, I still need Google Drive functionality to limit those permissions when accessing the same data using a (Chrome) browser.

Answer (score 1):

There is no view and insert-only permissions at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Drive 'appdata' feature added in 2013 may help somewhat.  Only the app can read/write files in 'appdata' so control can be limited by passwords that the app can manage.  Log files or data that doesn't require strict DBA control can be held in the public area of a Google Drive while all controlled data can be held in the special 'appdata' folder.  This is not the best solution since a bad actor could just delete the whole Google Drive.  A much better solution would be if Google provided different passwords for different levels of access to a single drive, folder, and/or file.